# Anyone please tell me what kind hinge (name of the hinge) used in this product?

Tags: wood, woodworking, furniture, hardware, self-assembly-furniture

Anyone please tell me what kind hinge (name of the hinge) used in this product ?
Name of the product is SNAP JACK from LIVING WITH JACK company.

[image]

Comment: ok RedGrittyBrick, please read this. https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/snapjack/snap-jack . in this theyhave mentioned in General material and hardware specification for Snap Jack below the page. now i watched this video watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJdz-DM7BbU . @isherwood

Comment: it seems there may be some confusion as to what you are calling a "hinge".   The hinge is just the pivot point. The upper part where the two pieces of wood are keyed together are not part of the hinge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Hinges

> **what kind hinge (name of the hinge) used in this product?**

That looks like simple pin (perhaps steel) in a drilled hole and a couple of spacers (perhaps plastic). I don't know of a specific name for this simple arrangement. Nor for the compound hinge formed by the arrangement of three simple hinges to form a folding brace.

---

Addenda ...

[image: labelled detail of hinge mechanism]

In the [Snap-Jack furniture](http://www.livingwithjack.com/faqs/)

> All the fittings, and hinges are stainless steel, and the magnets and keepers are nickel plated, the hinge spacers are plastic

So the hinges are basically exactly as I said above. The magnets are not part of the hinge itself.

---

## Latches

> **I think [...] a rare earth magnet [...] was used as a hinge**

In the [Snap-Jack furniture](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/snapjack/snap-jack), magnets are not part of the hinge - magnets are used to hold the furniture parts in the fully-closed and fully-open positions. Magnets are also used to help hold the chairs and tables into the wall-mount in the stored position.

> Magnetic safety latches

These magnets are not part of the hinges.

---

## Part names

All these parts are available separately from most hardware stores.

- steel rod
- steel or plastic washers (maybe spacers too)
- disk magnets (screw mounted or epoxy into recess)
- keepers (or use a steel washer and a short wood-screw)

I would use a drill-press with a table rotated 90° to drill the holes for the pins.

Comment: +1 I think they are simply called [*pin hinges*](https://www.woodcraft.com/blog_entries/boxes-with-pin-hinges)

Comment: Thanks for your response RedGrittyBrick. Actually i think this one is a Rare earth magnets (neodymium magnets) which was used a an hinge. what do you think RedGrittyBrick?

Comment: @oryxonfire magnets aren't used for load-bearing or stressed parts in furniture hinges. They might be used to lightly hold the strut in the open or closed positions but if so, they are not visible in your photo and are not strictly part of the hinge mechanism itself.

Comment: ok RedGrittyBrick, please read this. https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/snapjack/snap-jackjust . in this theyhave mentioned in General material and hardware specification for Snap Jack below the page. now i watched this video watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJdz-DM7BbU

Comment: `Precision fitted magnets secure this table in both the open and closed positions.` This says to me that the magnets hold position. They don't function as the hinge itself.

Comment: @isherwood thats what i think. please read the above comment.

Comment: [This picture](https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/018/072/515/6dca0ee3900d66a1e9fc81856edc4481_original.jpg?w=680&fit=max&v=1503744825&auto=format&q=92&s=cc2a80fa455a88a768321554640ae1c9) on the [Kickstarter Page](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/snapjack/snap-jack) shows the magnets being used.

Comment: @oryxonfire: See addenda to answer.

Comment: rare earth magnets are too brittle for use in a load-bearing applications

Comment: Thank you @Redgrittybrick for your detailed explanation. I appreciate your quick response. And thanks to who are all participated in this question give their valuable time on this.